# HTTP Sink Connector not Batching the messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using below HTTP Sink connector config and it is still sending records one by one. It is supposed to send data in a batch of 50 messages.

```
{
"name": "HTTPSinkConnector_1",
"config": {
    "topics": "topic_1",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.http.HttpSinkConnector",
    "http.api.url": "http://localhost/messageHandler",
    "request.method": "POST",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:19092",
    "confluent.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "batching.enabled": true,
    "batch.max.size": 50,
    "reporter.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:19092",
    "reporter.result.topic.name": "success-responses",
    "reporter.result.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "reporter.error.topic.name": "error-responses",
    "reporter.error.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "request.body.format": "json"
 }
}
```

Could someone please suggest if any another property is missing?

Comment: Do the messages that need to be batched contain the same Kafka header? Because according to the documentation, "The HTTP Sink connector does not batch requests for messages containing Kafka header values that are different."

Comment: @JaimeCaffarel In our case the header keys are same but values are different. Will it batch requests?

Comment: As the comment says, different values are not batched

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks, do you know is there any specific reason why HTTP Sink Connector do not support batching if messages has different header values? In our case there are 1000+ topics and all of them have headers.

Comment: It's not open source, so no, I don't know... Kafka Connect isn't your only option. Write your own code to do the same, or look into broader ETL tools (that are free and don't require Confluent Enterprise license) like Apache Nifi

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the options, will explore them. Also, is there any way to drop the headers and batch the requests messages?

Comment: @DixitSingla Use Kafka Streams to create a new topic without headers, or manually `aggregate` , as answered

Answer (score 1):

> The HTTP Sink connector **does not** batch requests for messages containing Kafka header values that are different.

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/http/current/overview.html#features

The workaround would be to either:

- remove the headers
- use Kafka Streams to manually window the data on your own into a new topic, which the connector reads